# Javascript - Regular expressions not working on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, regex, tinymce

I'm currently building my first tinymce plugin for wordpress. The plugin is adding columns to the content and it is already working when I'm just using 1 set of columns. But my regular expression fail when I'm using multiple set of columns (see example).

Here is my code that is getting shortcodes out from html in tinymce:

```
function getShortcode (content) {
  return content.replace(
    /<div class="row">(.*)<\/div>/g,
    function (a, b) {
      var out = '';
      out = b.replace(
        /<div class="large-6 columns"><p>([\s\S]*?)<\/p><\/div><div class="large-6 columns"><p>([\s\S]*?)<\/p><\/div>/g,
        function (a, col_1, col_2) {    
          return '[row][col6]' + col_1 + '[/col6][col6]' + col_2 + '[/col6][/row]';
        });
      return out;
    });
}
```

[Here is a jsfiddle showing that it works on one element, but fail when i have multiple sets of columns.](https://jsfiddle.net/kr88b97x/5/)

This is the code for one set of columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns"><p>Content 1</p></div>
    <div class="large-6 columns"><p>Content 2</p></div>
</div>
```

When getting the shortcode for one set of columns it works great and returns (see jsfiddle):

```
[row][col6]Content 1[/col6][col6]Content 2[/col6][/row]
```

and here is the result when I'm trying to get multiple sets of colums:

```
[row][col6]Content 1[/col6][col6]Content 2[/col6][/row]
</div><div class="row">[row][col6]Content 1[/col6][col6]Content 2[/col6][/row]
```

As you see, I get some unwanted div closing and opening tags when I'm using multiple sets of columns.

I'm pretty new to regular expression, and want to learn more. Can someone help me with a solution and explain to me what I did wrong, so I can learn from my mistakes?

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't gotten a ton of comments saying *you should never use regex to parse HTML* :) And regex isn't well suited for cases like your. The first `Replace` doesn't know which `</div>` to match with the start tag `<div class="row">`. Since you're using greedy search - `*` without `?` - it'll match the last one it finds and in your case it's the end tag for the second row. You get them both at the same time. You could change it to *non greedy*, but that would give you the end tag for the column instead. So in short - find another way than regex. A search here at SO will help you

Comment: @ClasG Hahah, yeah I understand. I'm just trying to use the same method wordpress is using in their wpeditimage tinymce plugin. I have tried searching for methods solving this with no luck. I found a really good wordpress feature on how to "convert" my shortcodes to html again, but I need to convert html to shortcodes... Do you have any good advice for what to search for?